# How to make first select option default value, selected and disabled in webform Drupal 7?

Tags: webforms, drupal-7

I have created a multi select dropdown in Drupal 7 webform, and I want to first option value selected and disabled so that nobody can choose that option.

`opt_key|!My option text
0|please choose options |selected |disabled
2|2
3|3
4|4
5|5`

Just want to make 0 as selected and disabled.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Without more information about your current implementation, I think readers versed in Drupal may struggle to help you. Can you add some code or other information to your post?

Comment: This question has been abandoned, so can be closed.